# Hibernate 5.1.16.Final + MSSQL + Java7 + C3P0

Tags: hibernate

Estou usando, com sucesso, o hibernate para consultar um banco MS SQL, mas recebo a mensagem que não devo usar em produção.

```
Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
....
2018-10-23 18:01:40 WARN  ConnectionProviderInitiator:219 - HHH000022: c3p0 properties were encountered, but the c3p0 provider class was not found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored.
```

Optei em usar o provider C3P0 mas quando incluo a propriedade em "hibernate.cfg.xml"

```
 <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

recebo a falha.

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
...
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider] as strategy [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
```

Meu POM.XML

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.16.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Como devo incia corretamente o provider?

Comment: Tente adicionar essa dependência https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/5.3.7.Final

Comment: Sem sucesso ... por conta da versão tentei com .... https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/5.1.16.Final/jar

Comment: Essa outra e mantendo a anterior https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/mchange-commons-java/0.2.15

Comment: Também nada.. mesmo erro

Comment: Esqueci de citar que se eu não forçar a propriedade ele até acha o c3p0 mas da esse erro .. 2018-10-23 18:01:40 WARN  ConnectionProviderInitiator:219 - HHH000022: c3p0 properties were encountered, but the c3p0 provider class was not found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored.

Comment: Tentei novamente sem a propriedade do provider e com as dependências que citou .. e mesmo assim persiste o erro .